# symfony3 route: doesnt work from a routing file but it does from another

Tags: php, symfony

I have two routing files in my project:

```
event.yml
user.yml
```

I'm trying to add a new route to event.yml file :

```
registro_eventos:
    path: /evento
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:registroevento }
```

The function registroeventoAction on the `EventController.php` file is:

```
public function registroeventoAction(Request $request)
{
    $evento = new Evento();
    $form = $this->createForm(EventoType::class, $evento);
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Event:registroeventos.html.twig',array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));

}
```

When I try the route, the answer is `err_invalid_response` (just like if the route doesnt exists).

I've tryied to add different routes to the same file and always the same amswer (I have to say that the previous routes in this file works ok! )

**Finally I've added the route to the `user.yml` file and works!**

Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Arturo

Adding information:

The content of the app/config/routing.yml is:

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix: /
```

The content of the AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml is:

```
app_user:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/user.yml"
prefix: /

app_event:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/event.yml"
prefix: /

app_homepage:
path: /
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:login }

app_candidato:
resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/candidato.yml"
prefix: /
```

This is the content of AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/event.yml (this routes are working propperly, but if I add a new route, this doesn't)

```
home:
path: /home
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:index }

indice_eventos:
path: /indice_eventos
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:indice }

inscriptos_evento:
path: /inscriptos/{slugevento}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:listadoInscriptos, slugevento:null   }    

inscriptos_excel:
path: /{_filename}.{_format}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:excelInscriptos, _format: xlsx }    


inicia_registro:
path: /inicia_registro
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:iniciaRegistro }    

datos_personales:
path: /datos_personales
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:datosPersonales }
```

And finally the content of AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/user.yml

```
login:
path: /login
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:login }

login_check:
path: /login_check

logout:
path: /logout


register:
path: /register
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:register }

user_email_test:
path: /email-test
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:emailTest }
methods: [POST]

user_edit:
path: /my-data
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:editUser }

usuarios_list:
path: /usuarios
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:usuarios }

usuarios_search:
path: /search
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:User:search }  

registro_eventos:
path: /evento
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:registroevento }   

editar_evento:
path: /evento/{idevento}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:editevento, idevento:null }  

borrar_evento:
path: /delevento/{idevento}
defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Event:deleteEvento, idevento:null }
```

Comment: How are you importing these files?

Comment: Where are your routings files ? Are they correctly defined in app/config/routing.yml ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply!  I will response your questions adding the information to the ppost

Answer (score 0):

In file `app/config/routing.yml` you should add the routing files:

```
my_events:
    prefix: /events
    resource: "@appBundle/Resources/config/event.yml"
```

You can access using `"PATH/events/evento"`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I've just edited the post with the content of all the yml routing files. I will trying to do what you say here, but the strange thing (like netflix!) is that the old routes on event.yml are working!